# How do I determine if there are any files currently being uploaded in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

We allow uploading large files (video) in our application. Is there any way for me to know that a file is currently being uploaded? For example, in classic ASP, we use a 3rd party component that uses the temp directory to buffer the file while it is being uploaded.

It would be nice to know this before I restart IIS or the server and kill somebody's upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adjusting my Google search, I found a link that mentions the location of the file buffer in ASP.Net.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\[app name]\[hex dir]\[hex dir]\uploads
```

Answer (score 0):

You could upload a file using some temporary name and then when it's complete you renamed it to something else. Then you could check the folder for files matching your temporary naming pattern and restart accordingly.